# How to show White Space character in android studio as Eclipse tool

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I know where to show `White Space character` (Image 1) in Eclipse.

[image]

Image 2 indicated what I want to show same as in Android Studio tool.
[image]

I don't know where to set `White Space character` in Android Studio.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Before Android Studio 1.2:

`File`->`Settings`->in `IDE-Settings`, `Editor`->`Appearance`->toggle `Show whitespaces` on

After Android Studio 1.2:
`File`->`Settings`->`Editor`->`General`->in `Appearance`->toggle `Show whitespaces` on

Or just search `show whitespaces` in searchbox in `Settings`, you can also find the way to show white space.

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio 1.2

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > toggle "Show Whitespace"

Answer (score 2):

## Android Studio show whitespace

> v4.0

Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance

jetbrains://AndroidStudio/settings?name=Editor--General--Appearance

[image]